# Linux Mint - настройка переключения рабочих столов

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Вопрос такой - как можно настроить переключение между рабочими столами с помощью жестов? Хочу сделать настройку а-ля MacOS, чтобы свайпом вправо или влево был переход между workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала узнать, какими командами через терминал переключаются столы в linux-mint, затем создать в easystroke жесты и назначить им команды (`sudo apt install easystroke`).

Я не знаю, какие конкретно команды используются в cinnamon и у меня его нет чтобы проверить, но можете попробовать [вот этот](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41093/is-there-a-command-to-go-a-specific-workspace) способ.